# "Even though" contradiction

Tags: grammar, sentence, semantics

> *Clause*
>   Run!
>   **This single-word command is also a clause, even though it does seem to have a subject**. With a direct command, it is not necessary to include the subject, since it is obviously the person or people you are talking to: in other words, the clause really reads "[You] run!". You should not usually use direct commands in your essays, except in quotations.

The **bold** sentence above basically said :

> This single-word command is also a clause, ***despite the fact*** that it does seem to have a subject.

Doesn't this imply that clause usually doesn't have a subject? Why does it contradict itself?

Comment: I'd say they screwed up and it was supposed to be "even though it does **not** seem to have a subject."

Answer (score 3):

The bold sentence in the question basically said :

> This single-word command is also a clause, ***despite the fact*** that it does seem to have a subject.

So it is concluded that they screwed it up and it was actually supposed to be "even though it does **not** seem to have a subject."